# List of un-assigned keys in Blender 2.69

Tags: customization

How can one obtain a list of un-assigned keys in Blender (i.e. Q, Alt-Q)? Is there a script for this?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can view all the shortcuts in *User Preferences > Input*. There is also an operator to test for key conflicts (*Space > Search > Test key configuration for conflicts*). Note that this prints to the console.

Comment: What would be the semantics of this operator? I've searched for it on the online manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be nice and practical to list all un-assigned keys, since there obviously are too many posibilities with combinations. Furthermore, **same keys can be used in different modes and contexts without conflicts**, which extends the possibilities even further.

However, as gandalf3 suggested, you can view all shortcuts in **User Preferences** > Input. Also, when switching **Filter Type** to *Key Binding*, it allows you to search specific key that is currently assigned:

[image]

If nothing is filtered, then congratulations, it hasn't yet been assigned to any operators among all contexts. You can use it 100% safely:

[image]

Comment: for what it's worth, I still think it would be useful to display the list of unassigned keyboard shortcuts upfront, rather than try/error manually one by one. I mean: computers are perfect for those loop tasks...

Comment: @ling Couldn't agree more. I also wish there was a way to search for explicitly the exact key you're entering in the search key binding field. Even made a request for it that you could support here: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/y9nz/